# any danger to not substituting user@machine in shell output online?

Tags: security, shell, internet-security

Online, I usually obfuscate my username and machine name when sharing terminal output.  Is there any real danger to publishing my `user:~ machine$` online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not a FQDN? No. If its not on the internet, no.

If someone knows what system it is, and what your username is, and can be bothered to brute force your password or try matching it to one of many lists of compromised usernames/password pairs? maybe.

So "user124@lfx1" is fine. "john@seekritproject.evilprojects.com" may not be. I'm perfectly fine with posting geek@phoebe$ online, but not my publicly facing servers.

That said, there's folks using username/password lists to brute force systems and if your security is good, its not just a username/password. You have key based auth and or two factor authentication. In that case, you could have both your username and password compromised, and you'd possibly still leave an attacker flapping in the breeze, they don't have your other factor.

So... it shouldn't matter, but I wouldn't do it *anyway*

Answer (score 2):

In terms of physical security, there is no danger because your host name is just used to identify your computer on your local network. It is not sent over the Internet. And your user name is just used in your computer. Even other computers in the local network can't see it.

But it may help the attacker if your network is compromised to identify your computer and log in to your computer using your username if s/he knows your password or finds a way to crack it. As long as you are sure that your network is not compromised, you don't actually need to obfuscate them.

One important thing may be just your privacy when your username or computer name includes your name and you don't want strangers to know about you.